# Move from TFS 2012 Express to full version on different PC

Tags: tfs

I am running a TFS server for little home projects... 2012 express on a Windows 7 SP2 machine. I am now upgrading to a Windows Server 2012 machine, and full version of TFS 2012. Is there a way to backup my current TFS setup, and restore it to my new PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide should show you how to upgrade from express to a full version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj620928.aspx

This describes specifics for moving to new hardware: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj620930.aspx